# AWS S3 GET returns status code 403

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using `node aws-sdk` with a user who has been set up with the following policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1458935963000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket1/*"
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

The bucket itself does not have any explict policy attached to it. `Permissions` are set as follows:
[image]

The following produces `403`:

```
<video src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket1/default21.mp4">
</video>
```

Bucket name has been changed, but it does exist on S3 along with the video. Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**
Getting the same result even if `aws-sdk` is booted with the `root/owner` of S3 account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<video>` tag is not using the authentication mechanism that your nodejs code has setup.

the video tag gets loaded in a browser, and the browser knows nothing about he AWS SDK or your node server.

you need to [use a pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) for the video tag.

generate the URL on the server, and then use that url in the video tag. for example, if you're using Express:

```
router.get("/whatever", function(req, res, next){


  var params = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'default21.mp4'};
  var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);

  res.render("some/view", {
    videoUrl: url
  });

});
```